# SOLR , applying functions to parameters within queries

Tags: solr

I’m new to SOLR and I'm currently working with version 7.4 and require your help for the following problem.
With standard embedded SOLR's query's parsers, is there a possibility to use custom's functions on parameters as the following example?

Field1: CustomeFunction(“Blabla”)

The goal is to use the same function when loadingfield1 and then apply some query with this same function applied to parameters.

Following is a more concrete example as requested:

The idea is to filter the result by a function used when loading

In my example, I would like to compare field that are filled at loading time using embedded function:

Here is my loader defined within db-data-config.xml:

```
<entity name="suspect" query="select UID,                                        
                            trim(FIELD1) AS FIELD1,…,                                    
                            trim (FIELD1) AS FIELD1C    
                            trim(FIELD1) AS FIELD1C _D1,
                            trim(FIELD1) AS FIELD1C_D234, ..
            from myview"  
transformer=
"ch.eri.thirdparty.solr.handler.dataimport.ReadFileTransformer">
        <field column="UID" name="id" />
        <field column=" FIELD1" name="field1" encoder=”C1”/>
        <field column=" FIELD1C" name="field1c" encoder=”C1”/>
<field column=" FIELD1D_D1" name=" field1c_digit1"/>
        <field column=" FIELD1C_D234" name=" field1c_digit234"/>
```

Now during loading a fill PHN_D1 and PH_D123 with my customized ch.eri.thirdparty.solr.handler.dataimport.ReadFileTransformer as following:

```
@Override
public Object transformRow(Map<String, Object> row, Context context) {
    List<Map<String, String>> fields = context.getAllEntityFields();
    //Map<String,Object> mem = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    for (Map<String, String> field : fields) {
        // Check if this field has readFile="true" specified in the data-config.xml
        String encoder = field.get("encoder");
        String columnName = field.get(DataImporter.COLUMN);
        //if(mem.containsKey(columnName))
        //   row.put(columnName,mem.get(columnName));

        if(encoder!=null) {

            columnName = field.get(DataImporter.COLUMN);

            Object toEncode= row.get(columnName); //0000
            if(toEncode!=null && toEncode instanceof String) {
              try {//need to work on toENcode
                Encoder codec = EncoderHelper.getEncoder(encoder);
                String code =String.valueOf(codec.encode(toEncode));
                row.put(columnName, code);
                if (encoder.equals("C1")) {
                   if(code.length()==4) {
                     String prefix = code.substring(0,1);
                     String suffix =  code.substring(1);
                     //override
                     row.put(columnName + "_D1", prefix);
                     row.put(columnName + "_D234", suffix);
                   }
                   else {
                     //override
                     row.put(columnName + "_D1", "X");
                     row.put(columnName + "_D234", "XXX");
                   }

                }

              }catch (Throwable t){
                LOGGER.error("Error while reading file!!! ",t);
              }
            }
            else {
              row.put(columnName, "NULL");
            }
          }
        }
    return row;
}
```

Now, when querying results   I would like to apply function to my parameters and use built-in function in SOLR and want to avoid do it in from my client.

As an example:

```
field1, field1c,field1c_digit1,field1c_digit123 
TOTO,   T300   ,             T,          300
COCO,   C200   ,             C,          200    
RIRI,   R600   ,             R,          600
```

Ideally, I would like to test the following parameter TOXOLH, the encryption of this parameter gives T240 (Soundex) and would do something like this:

```
Substing(Encode(TOXOL),0,1) == field1c_digit1 AND 
abs(Integer.valueOf(substing(Encode(TOXOL),1,3))- field1c_digit123) <70
```

TOTO should be the result.

My point is to use functions within queries  is because I don’t guess what our customers want to do and which rules they want to implement (each one might have its own “strange” rules made internally by their COs i.e. in this use case they have some rules on the first digit and some delta on the third last digit). I thought it was easier to delegate all this to a custom implementation of SOLR for each customers and that our application gives basic things through a generic interface to have a separation of concern.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing what you want to do - could you add a proper example? The `{!func}` query parser allows running function in queries or filter queries.

Comment: thx  MatsLindh , I did update my question with a more concrete example. I'm currently trying to use {!func}...

Comment: I strongly suggest decomposing the soundex entry when indexing, then do the same before sending your query to Solr. That way you can use `fq=field1c_digit1:T&fq={!frange l=-70 u=70}sub(field1c_digit123,240)`, without having to do any substring operations or soundex encoding in the functions themselves.

Comment: Thx MatsLindh , I think I understand your point for performance concern.

Comment: Thx a lot MatsLindh
The index part when loading data is done already this way. 
For the functions embedded within queries, I added some contextual description in my question.
What do you think?

Comment: Assuming that using functions like those gives poor performance, I would like to understand why and maybe find a way to implement them the optimum way by simplifying them understanding the underlying mechanism.

Comment: The reason is that any change that allows you to do the work up front (and I don't think there's a existing function in Solr for creating a Soundex signature - you'll have to write that yourself in that case) will assue better performance. You've already done the work when indexing (so that a query can be resolved easily). Instead of having to invoke a function on many values and consider the result, the query can just reference the index and resolve the valid set of documents directly from the index.

Comment: _Instead of having to invoke a function on many values and consider the result, the query can just reference the index and resolve the valid set of documents directly from the index_ what about separation of concerns, maybe is there a way to preprocess the request(transforming the request) on the server side SOLR , and then launch the query with index-like parameters?

Comment: That's what I suggested - when querying, do the soundex transformation, then issue the query as filter query matching your `field1c_digit` and a separate matching your `field1c_digit123`. In my example I used a function for the second one, but even better would be to do `x-70` and `x+70` in your code, then do `field1c_digit123:[<first value> TO <second value>]`. That will not invoke any functions and is probably the most optimal way to query Solr. Combine the queries with OR between them if they're used together as a single `fq` to optimize cache usage.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not allowed to switch in chat. You said _when querying, do the Soundex transformation_ How may I do it on **SOLR server side**, not on my application server, is there a way to intercept the request and transform it? Your answer is exactly what I would like to have...

Comment: Do it in your application server. You're already doing the transformation before indexing, so it's best to use the same algorithm when you're creating the query as well.